# Cloud web scraping with requests returns nothing

Tags: heroku, web-scraping, redis, python-requests, python-rq

I'm trying to create a cog for my Discord bot that scrapes Indeed and returns info on job postings (position, company, location, etc). My bot is hosted on Heroku, which is where the issues start. I've tested my web scraper by itself and when implemented as a cog for my Discord bot locally. It works both times. However, when I tried to deploy it on Heroku, the cog stopped working.

I read that this was because cloud-hosting services have blacklists or something for web scraping apps and functions. So I tried to use rq as suggested in this post:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq

I did all the steps, added an additional worker, a worker.py file, and installed the Redis To Go addon. However, when I try to use the following, I receive nothing back:

```
url = get_url(job_title, location)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
# soup.find() returns None
```

I'm sure I just implemented something wrong, but can someone help me please? The full code is below:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn
ret = []


def get_url(position, location):
    '''Generate url from position and location'''
    template = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q={}&l={}'
    position = position.replace(" ", "+")
    location = location.replace(" ", "+")
    url = template.format(position, location)
    return url


def get_jobs(job_title, location):
    '''Max returned number of jobs is 15 per page.'''
    global ret
    url = get_url(job_title, location)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(f"Responses: {response}")

    ### This returns <Response [200]>

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    job_names = []
    for job_name in soup.find_all("h2", class_="jobTitle"):
        job_names.append(job_name.get_text())

    ### Each one just returns an empty list []
    
    companies = []
    for company in soup.find_all("span", class_="companyName"):
        companies.append(company.get_text())
    
    locations = []
    for location in soup.find_all("div", class_="companyLocation"):
        locations.append(location.get_text())
    
    salaries = []
    for salary in soup.find_all("div", class_="attribute_snippet"):
        if salary.get_text().startswith("$"):
            salaries.append(salary.get_text())
        else:
            salaries.append("Unknown")
    
    links = []
    for link in soup.find_all("a", class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("tapItem fs-unmask result"), href=True):
        link = link["href"]
        link = "https://indeed.com" + link
        links.append(link)
    
    ret = [job_names, companies, locations, salaries, links]
    print(ret)

    ### This returns [[], [], [], [], []]



class JobScraper(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):  # References whatever is passed through the client from discord
        self.client = client
        self.q = Queue(connection=conn)

    @commands.command(aliases=["job", "find_job", "find_jobs", "get_job", "get_jobs"])
    async def jobs(self, ctx, *, query):
        '''Scrapes Indeed.com for jobs and returns them.
        The input format should be "eve jobs [job title], [job location], [num returned]
        e.g. eve jobs ai researcher, san francisco, 3'''

        key_terms = query.split(",")
        key_terms = [term.strip() for term in key_terms]
        if len(key_terms) == 3:
            num_jobs = int(key_terms[2])
        else:
            num_jobs = 15
        
        # ret = get_jobs(key_terms[0], key_terms[1])
        job = self.q.enqueue(get_jobs, key_terms[0], key_terms[1])

        await ctx.send("Here is what I found:")
            
        for i in range(num_jobs):
            await ctx.send("```" +
                f"\nTitle: {ret[0][i]}" + 
                f"\nCompany: {ret[1][i]}" + 
                f"\nLocation: {ret[2][i]}" +
                f"\nSalary: {ret[3][i]}" + 
                f"\nLink: {ret[4][i]}" +
                "\n```")


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(JobScraper(client))
````

Comment: Try inspecting the response itself: `response = requests.get(url)`  log the `response.text` to see what the server is seeing. Generally when using cloud providers you should use some proxy as well.

Comment: This violates [Indeed's terms of service](https://www.indeed.com/legal#allusers): "Use of any automated system or software, whether operated by a third party or otherwise, to extract data from the Site (such as screen scraping or crawling) is prohibited." **Please respect their terms and stop doing this.** It is very likely that they have technical measures in place to prevent this from working, e.g. by serving different content (or not responding at all) to requests from AWS IP addresses. We're not going to help you violate terms like this.

Comment: Apologies, I was not aware of this. I just saw a tutorial online and thought it was an interesting project to do. I'll take it down then.